# What is the "validity scope" of a browser cookie?

Tags: web-browser, cookies, csrf

Consider the standard CSRF protection of a Ruby on Rails application: a CSRF token is embedded in the HTML page, while at the same time stored encrypted as part of the session cookie. When making a request, the embedded token is sent along the cookie, and the server can then check whether they match.

Suppose now to open the same application in two separate browser tabs. They will have different CSRF tokens and as such different session cookies. However, when I make post requests there are no CSRF issues.

This raises the question: what is the scope of a browser cookie? If the scope were global (i.e. valid across different browser tabs), then as soon as I opened the second tab the first session cookie would have been overwritten (as they come from the same origin and have the same key). But I can make POST requests from the first tab, and they do not fail, implying that each tab has its own set of cookies.

On the other hand, if I log in in one tab and open a second one, I obviously have an application session in the second tab too, implying that cookies are shared across browser tabs.

So then, what is the true "scope" of a browser cookie?

Answer (score 4):

> ... two separate browser tabs. They will have different CSRF tokens and as such different session cookies.

They don't. 
The same cookie is used whenever you access the same site within the same browser, i.e. the scope of the cookie is not the current tab but the current browser.

That's why it is usually also impossible to login into the same site with the same browser at the same time. There are browser extensions to limit the scope of the cookie to the current tab in order to make multi-login possible but by default the scope is the current browser.

To be more precise: if you switch to a different browser you have a different context for cookies. If you switch to a different browser profile you get also a different context. Same when switching to private mode. But if you switch only to a different tab or window then you have the same context.

Note that a cookie might be additionally restricted by the path on the site using a `path` argument and might also include subdomains using the `domain` argument. See the section "Scope of cookies" at [MDN:HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) for more details.

Comment: Unless i am overlooking something, they really do have different CSRF tokens, it is visible in the markup as a meta tag (for Rails applications that is). Or am i missing something trivial?

Comment: @danielf.: They will have the same *session cookie*. However, I think that Steffen Ullrich's answer partially answer your post, perhaps an addendum regarding the use of [CSRF tokens in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463422/csrf-can-i-use-a-cookie) could be added to explain the difference and why the scenario you describe happens.

Comment: @Yuriko: i guess then the question is more about how Ruby on Rails handles CSRF token. Thank you both for your input.

Comment: @danielf.: trying some ruby on rails using application like airbnb.com I get the same _csrf_token in all tabs on the same browser.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich if I open the exact same page, then yes, the tokens are the same. However if i open different pages of the same application, the token differs. I opend two different projects in gitlab, the tokens are different, and POST requests go through on both tabs.

I guess my understanding of how CSRF protection in Ruby on Rails works is still not complete.

Comment: @danielf.: It might be that these cookies have additional restrictions based on the path and thus different path might have different CSRF tokens both in HTML and as cookie. See updated answer. For airbnb.com I can not see any difference though, i.e. same token and cookie on all URL on the same site.

Comment: Does the origin of the web page participate in cookie scoping? Site A acquires cookies from domain D, site B sends ajax request to site D, assuming `withCredentials: true` and CORS allows anything, will browser attach cookies?

Comment: @PavelVoronin: I'm not sure what you are asking. Sites don't acquire cookies from other sites. Only the browser gets the cookie. And the browser will send the cookie only back to the domain (or a subdomain) where it came from.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. There are two SPAs hosted on different domain. I open two browser tabs. One for SPA1, and the second tab for SPA2. Both SPAs consume some API hosted on domain D.

I use SPA1 to authenticate against that API, so browser gets the response with Set-Cookie from D.

Now I switch to SPA2 and trigger some request to the API. Will browser attach the cookie?

We have origin of the code, executing in the browser, and origin of the cookie. The question is whether the origin of the code plays any role here?

Comment: @PavelVoronin: If you have a cross site request (SPA1-domain to D) and another cross site request (SPA2-domain to D) then the cookie send to D within origin SPA1 will also be sent within origin SPA2. This is unless the browser employs additional separation between the origins as in [Cookies Having Independent Partitioned State](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Ok, so having an API service accessible to any origin and using cookie for authentication makes it vulnerable to CSRF attack. And I see no mitigation option in this case.

Comment: @PavelVoronin: You deliberately allow cross-site access from all origins in your CORS policy. Please explain how do you think a cross-site request *forgery* is different from a valid cross-site request (non forgery) in your case.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, that's the problem, there's no way to distinguish. If bearer token is used for auth, each SPA should acquire it individually, so if one of the SPA belongs to malicious side, user must be tricked to authenticate.

Comment: @PavelVoronin: so don't use cookies then in this case so that you have full control over what gets send.